# riotjs compiler Source path does not exist

Tags: riot.js

I can't run riot commands using cmd. When i type:

```
riot foo.tag
```

result is:

```
Source path does not exist
```

I use windows. I tried from cmd, gitbash, cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I should use:

```
riot --new foo
```